# Updating Previously Made List?

Tags: .net, vb.net

So I make a List in a Background Worker with Start and End time etc for processing a TV Show list I put the Channel Name for the TV Show in it too. So now I wanna process the Channel's List aswell and it has the Channel Name and the Channel Livestream.

How can I make it so I add the Channel Stream to the List made in the Background Worker?

Code:

```
'Guide and Channel Information;
Public Class Channel

    Public Property Channel As String
    Public Property Stream As String
    Public Property Genre As String
    Public Property StartTime As String
    Public Property EndTime As String
    Public Property Programme As String
    Public Property Description As String

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Channel
        Return Stream
        Return Genre
        Return StartTime
        Return EndTime
        Return Programme
        Return Description
    End Function

End Class

'Make a List for the Guide Information;
Public Guide As New List(Of Channel)
Private Sub ProcessGuide_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles ProcessGuide.DoWork

    Try

        Dim nodelist As XmlNodeList
        Dim node As XmlNode

        'Create the XML Document;
        Dim xmld As XmlDocument
        xmld = New XmlDocument()

        'Load the XMLTV File;
        xmld.Load("http://104.233.125.128/gmtplus0.xmltv")

        'Loop through the Programme Nodes;
        nodelist = xmld.SelectNodes("/tv/programme")
        For Each node In nodelist

            'Here I am adding the Channel etc, But I will also need the stream etc added which is why I have a sub later on in the code to get and add the Stream. But how do I add it to this same Guide List?
            Guide.Add(New Channel() With {
                .Channel = node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("channel").Value,
                .StartTime = node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("start").Value,
                .EndTime = node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("stop").Value,
                .Programme = node.ChildNodes.Item(0).InnerText,
                .Description = node.ChildNodes.Item(1).InnerText
            })

        Next

        ProcessChannels.RunWorkerAsync()

    Catch ex As Exception

        'Error trapping
        Console.Write(ex.ToString(), "TTTTTdsg")

    End Try

End Sub

'Process the Channel Information;
Dim AllChannels As List(Of Channel) = New List(Of Channel)()
Dim EntertainmentChannels As List(Of Channel) = New List(Of Channel)()
Dim KidsChannels As List(Of Channel) = New List(Of Channel)()
Dim SportsChannels As List(Of Channel) = New List(Of Channel)()
Dim DocumentaryChannels As List(Of Channel) = New List(Of Channel)()
Dim NewsChannels As List(Of Channel) = New List(Of Channel)()
Dim MusicChannels As List(Of Channel) = New List(Of Channel)()
Public Sub ProcessChannels_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles ProcessChannels.DoWork

    'Try to Load the Channel Data;
    Try

        'Connect to the Proxy Source and Prepare the Response;
        Dim source As Net.HttpWebRequest = Net.WebRequest.Create("http://gameshare.io/pragma/channels.php")
        Dim response As Net.HttpWebResponse = source.GetResponse

        'Load the HTML and Convert the JSON to a Readable Array;
        Dim reader As IO.StreamReader = New IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
        Dim html As String = reader.ReadToEnd
        Dim json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(html)

        '=========================================================
        '=========================================================
        'Here is where I need to not add the Guide info to a NEW Channel/Guide/List I need to add it to the same one
        'that is made in ProcessGuide_DoWork but how?

        'Process All Channels;
        For i As Integer = 0 To json("Quantity").ToString - 1
            For Each Row In json("All Channels")
                AllChannels.Add(New Channel() With {
                    .Channel = Row(i)("title").ToString,
                    .Stream = Row(i)("stream").ToString
                })
            Next
        Next

        'Process Enterainment Channels
        For i As Integer = 0 To json("EQuantity").ToString - 1
            For Each Row In json("Entertainment")
                EntertainmentChannels.Add(New Channel() With {
                    .Channel = Row(i)("title").ToString,
                    .Stream = Row(i)("stream").ToString
                })
            Next
        Next

        'Process Kids Channels;
        For i As Integer = 0 To json("KQuantity").ToString - 1
            For Each Row In json("Kids")
                KidsChannels.Add(New Channel() With {
                    .Channel = Row(i)("title").ToString,
                    .Stream = Row(i)("stream").ToString
                })
            Next
        Next

        'Process Sports Channels;
        For i As Integer = 0 To json("SQuantity").ToString - 1
            For Each Row In json("Sports")
                SportsChannels.Add(New Channel() With {
                    .Channel = Row(i)("title").ToString,
                    .Stream = Row(i)("stream").ToString
                })
            Next
        Next

        'Process Documentary Channels;
        For i As Integer = 0 To json("DQuantity").ToString - 1
            For Each Row In json("Documentary")
                DocumentaryChannels.Add(New Channel() With {
                    .Channel = Row(i)("title").ToString,
                    .Stream = Row(i)("stream").ToString
                })
            Next
        Next

        'Process News Channels;
        For i As Integer = 0 To json("NQuantity").ToString - 1
            For Each Row In json("News")
                NewsChannels.Add(New Channel() With {
                    .Channel = Row(i)("title").ToString,
                    .Stream = Row(i)("stream").ToString
                })
            Next
        Next

        'Process Music Channels;
        For i As Integer = 0 To json("MQuantity").ToString - 1
            For Each Row In json("Music")
                MusicChannels.Add(New Channel() With {
                    .Channel = Row(i)("title").ToString,
                    .Stream = Row(i)("stream").ToString
                })
            Next
        Next

        'Add all the Channels to the Channels ComboBox;
        ChannelsBox.Items.AddRange(allchannels.ToArray)

        'The Channels are now ready to be used, Tell the user to Select a Channel;
        ChannelsBox.Text = "Select a Channel..."

    Catch ex As Exception

        'Channel Data couldn't be loaded;
        ErrorImage.Width = "640"
        ErrorImage.Height = "391"
        ErrorImage.Visible = True

    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: You conflated 2 distinct bits of data.  After you processed the xml, you have ONE (1) entry for each (e.g. AMC, TruTV etc).  In the second loop, you will have MANY programs associated with each channel but no where to store them. The Guide info appears to represent the associated Channel using the `'title'` element.  Also a) there is no need for all those special lists; if channel had a Genre property you could classify them based on the current loop: `Kids`, `Sports` etc.  b) you will likely run into more problems later storing everything as string.  The DateTime for instance.

Comment: @Plutonix Yeah I was thinking of doing that Genre thing but I dont know how to like get only the channels with a Specific genre to convert using .ToArray

Comment: `Dim kidsPrograms = AllChannels.Where(Function (w) w.Genre = "Kids").ToList()`  `Genre` would actually go on a `Programme` list since a channel can vary its broadcasts.

Comment: @Plutonix Oh wow that worked first try and made my app load way faster thanks! Still need help on the main issue doe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code needs to be significantly reworked.  First, you should turn on `Option Strict`; code like this will not compile since it uses late-binding:

```
For Each Row In json("All Channels")
```

Fundamentally, once you parse the XML, you have *one* entry in the list for each channel.  You cannot then iterate the json TV show list and plug them into that list: there are *many* TV shows for each channel.  You don't have an array or list to store the multiple shows per channel.

There is also no need for a BackGroundWorker.  Rather than looping thru an `Object` and manually creating those lists, if you deserialize to a typed object JSON.NET will create all those lists for you in just a few ticks.

So, you need one class to link a URL to a channel (`TVGChannel`) and one class to contain the data for a TV broadcast. One of the properties for the show list/Guide is the channel it is one.  The XML data includes a `Category` for each show which would seem to be more interesting than a *channel* category.

*Hopefully*, the `channel` element in the XML really is designed to specify a channel indicated by `title` in the json and it is not an accident of the data that they match.  It looks more like it is supposed to reference something in the channel section in the same XML, but those just have URLs.

#### Programme class

```
Public Enum ProgrammeGenre
    Entertainment
    Kids
    Sports
    Documentary
    News
    Music
    Other
End Enum

Public Class Programme
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Title As String                 ' episode Title
    Public Property Description As String

    Public Property Channel As TVGChannel

    Public Property Genre As ProgrammeGenre

    Public Property StartTime As DateTime
    Public Property EndTime As DateTime

    Public Property Category As String
    Public Property EpisodeId As String
    Public Property Stars As Decimal

    Public Sub New()
        Genre = ProgrammeGenre.Other
    End Sub
 End Class
```

As you can see, I expanded it for a few other elements and changed some types, most notably the start and end times to `DateTime`.  The `Category` property stores the category from the XML, while the `Genre` is the result of which list it is in:

```
thisPrgURL = myProgrammes(n).Channel.stream
```

#### TVGContainer, TVGChannel

```
Public Class TVGChannel
    Public Property stream As String
    Public Property title As String

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return title
    End Function
End Class

Public Class TVGContainer
    'Public Property Quantity As String
    '...
    <JsonProperty("All Channels")>
       Private Property _AllChannels As TVGChannel()()

    ' none of these are really very useful:
    Public Property Entertainment As TVGChannel()()
    Public Property Kids As TVGChannel()()
    Public Property Sports As TVGChannel()()
    Public Property Documentary As TVGChannel()()
    Public Property News As TVGChannel()()
    Public Property Music As TVGChannel()()

    Friend ReadOnly Property AllChannels As TVGChannel()
        Get
            Return _AllChannels(0)
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

None of those `?Quantity` properties are of much value and the only role for the channel list subsets is for the Genre property on `Programme` - they could all be commented out.  I dunno why they provide them as a jagged array; I didnt want to have to deal with it, so the JSON will go into `_AllChannels` when it is deserialized, but the code will use the `AllChannels` property.

#### Form level variables

```
Private myPrograms As List(Of Programme)
Private ChannelGuide As TVGContainer
```

#### Parse the Guide

You need to have the Guide built *before* you process the XML so the channels are available to assign to each show:

```
Private Sub ParseGuide()

    Dim jstr = from whereever
    ChannelGuide = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of TVGContainer)(jstr)

End Sub
```

By deserialing to a typed object, there is no need to parse all that stuff one by one, and it should be much (much) faster; `ChannelGuide` will contain all those arrays.

#### Create the Program List (XML)

I made significant changes to how the XML is processed.  Most were in the interest of speed, less maintenance or more reliable processing:

```
Private Sub ParseXMLTV()
    Dim nodelist As XmlNodeList
    Dim node As XmlNode

    Dim xmld As New XmlDocument()
    xmld.Load("http://104.233.125.128/gmtplus0.xmltv")

    myPrograms = New List(Of Programme)
    nodelist = xmld.SelectNodes("/tv/programme")
    Dim p As Programme

    For Each node In nodelist
        p = New Programme()

        Dim dt = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("start").Value,
                           "yyyyMMddHHmmss KKKK", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).DateTime
        p.StartTime = dt
        dt = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("stop").Value,
                           "yyyyMMddHHmmss KKKK", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).DateTime
        p.EndTime = dt

        ' now, find the channel indicated
        Dim ch = node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("channel").Value
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(ch) = False Then
            Dim tvgc = ChannelGuide.AllChannels.FirstOrDefault(Function(q) q.title = ch)
            If tvgc IsNot Nothing Then
                p.Channel = tvgc
            Else
                ' ToDo: add an UNKNOWN channel to avoid NRE
            End If
        End If

        p.Genre = GetGenre(ch)

        For Each n As XmlNode In node.ChildNodes
            Select Case n.Name
                Case "title"
                    p.Name = n.InnerText
                Case "sub-title"
                    p.Title = n.InnerText
                Case "desc"
                    p.Description = n.InnerText
                Case "star-rating"
                    p.Stars = Convert.ToDecimal(n.InnerText.Split(" "c)(0))
                Case "episode-num"
                    p.EpisodeId = n.InnerText
                Case "category"
                    p.Category = n.InnerText
            End Select
        Next

        myPrograms.Add(p)

    Next
End Sub

Private Function GetGenre(ch As String) As ProgrammeGenre
    ' this is not needed - the XML provides a show category
    ' "Drama" or "SitCom" is more interesting than `Entertainment`

    If ChannelGuide.Documentary(0).
                FirstOrDefault(Function(f) f.title = ch) IsNot Nothing Then
        Return ProgrammeGenre.Documentary
    ElseIf ChannelGuide.Entertainment(0).
                FirstOrDefault(Function(f) f.title = ch) IsNot Nothing Then
        Return ProgrammeGenre.Entertainment
    ElseIf ... 
        ' repeat for others
    Else
        Return ProgrammeGenre.Other
    End If
End Function
```

#### Usage

```
ParseGuide()
If ChannelGuide IsNot Nothing AndAlso ChannelGuide.AllChannels.Count > 0 Then
    ParseXMLTV()
End If
dgvTV.DataSource = myPrograms
```

The whole thing take 6 seconds to run (including download times and posting to the DGV), so there isnt really a reason for a `BackGroundWorker`.  It would be faster without the cruft of fishing out the *show* Genre based on a *channel* category...and there are a lot of both of them that are missing.

[image]

The `EndTime`, `Category`, Episode ID and Star Rating are all scrolled off to the right.

---

The `DateTime` parsing may need work, but I have no idea where I can find the docs for this API.

Comment: Wow huge answer I didn't expect this o.o Do you mind if I could add you on skype and show you my Full Code to see if anything else is noob level? (If so Skype: Shiny-MK)

Comment: Im trying to read it but honestly not even sure its actually related, Some of it might be but alot of it seems to just be adding in un-necessary stuff like Im not interested too much in adding the TV SHow Description Genre Star Rating etc Add me on my skype and my app im tryna make will look make my question make sense.

Comment: You can always remove the parts you dont plan to use - in part they are there to show how to parse items other than string and a slightly better approach using the name rather than `ChildNodes.Item(0).InnerText`

Comment: If this answers the question, please click the checkmark so it moves off the Unanswered List. Marking them answered and upvoting Qs or As which helped you (even if not attached to a Q of yours) helps others find good answers, and shows you participate in the process.

Comment: Not really sure if it sorts my issue doe like I dont want any of this un-necessary stuff I just want to know how I can combine the two lists. Ill mark it as answer for now and look through it soon (Busy atm)

Comment: Ok so I just came back to get this going since I finally have free time. Im a bit confused on the Parse Guide function - What exactly am I meant to replace "From wheerever" with?

Comment: Where ever you get the Guide json from.  In the OP that appears to be `http://gameshare.io/pragma/channels.php`